# Integral computation - what's going on?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $\lambda >0$ and denote
$$
  \lim _{\varepsilon \to 0+} \frac{1}{|\xi                  
  |^2 - (\lambda  + i\varepsilon )^2} 
  = \frac{1}{|\xi                  
  |^2 - (\lambda  + i0)^2}.  
$$

For a function $f$ having compact support I'm trying to understand the computational step that goes:
$$
  \int \limits _{\mathbb{R}^n} |\hat{f}(\xi )|^2 \operatorname{Im}\frac{1}{|\xi                  
  |^2 - (\lambda  + i0)^2} \, d\xi 
  =\frac{\pi }{2\lambda } \int \limits _{|\xi | = \lambda } |\hat{f}(\xi )|^2 dS
$$
where $dS$ is the surface (Lebesgue) measure of the sphere $\{\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n: |\xi | = \lambda \}$ and $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.